# Empty variable in inline PHP

Tags: php

I'm having trouble verifying if a variable is empty using inline PHP. I currently have the following code:

```
<li>Nano: <?php if($Info['Nano'] == true): echo $Info['Nano']; else: echo $noRecords; endif; ?></li>
```

This is all good when `$Info['Nano']` is set, when it doesn't exist I get the the string stored in $noRecords but I also get an undefined index notice.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if it is set (*with `isset()`*):

```
<li>Nano: <?php if(isset($Info['Nano']) && $Info['Nano'] == true): 
                   echo $Info['Nano'];
                else: 
                   echo $noRecords;
                endif; ?></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just simply add a AND statement to also check, that it is set, like this:

```
<li>Nano: <?php if(isset($Info['Nano']) && $Info['Nano'] == true): echo $Info['Nano']; else: echo $noRecords; endif; ?></li>
```

If you want you also can use a ternary operator, so that the entire line is a little bit smaller:

```
<li>Nano: <?= (isset($Info['Nano']) && $Info['Nano'] == true)? $Info['Nano'] : $noRecords ?></li>
```